# How to return refresh token on custom redirect?

Tags: angularjs, google-oauth, gmail-api

I'm newcomer at gmail api. I'm already try to sendback refresh token and set approval_prompt = force when generate auth_url to get access_token but I'm still get only

```
 {
   "access_token" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
   "token_type" : "Bearer",
   "expires_in" : 3600
 }
```

Not have refresh_token

Can someone help me please ? Thank you so much for coming

Comment: Welcome thanapat! What server side technology are you using? Angularjs is not really relevant to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [Handling OAuth2.0 Response](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer?hl=en#handlingresponse) section of the Google Identity documentation, `refresh_token` will only be returned if the the access_type is offline.

> `refresh_token`   A token that may be used to obtain a new access token. Refresh tokens are valid until the user revokes access. This field is only present if access_type=offline is included in the authorization code request.